# Backbone underscore where returning empty array

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Rails app with Backbone on the frontend. I have several articles saved to the database. Each article has its own unique id obviously but they also have a publication_id. What I wish to do is grab every article with a specific publication_id. There may be multiple articles with associated with any given publication_id. I am trying to use underscores _.where function that comes with Backbone.

```
  delete_publication: function(id){

    var articles = new MyProject.Collections.Articles();
    console.log(articles.where({publication_id: id}));

  }
```

*Edit:* In this version if I just console.log articles I get:

```
child {length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object, constructor: function, url: "/articles"…}
```

The goal is to eventually grab the models, delete them from the database then update the view accordingly. For now I just want this to print the subset of articles that have that specific publication_id. This just prints an empty array to the console.

I have also tried this:

```
delete_publication: function(id){
  var articles = new MyProject.Collections.Articles();
  articles.fetch({
    success: function(data){
      console.log(  data.where({publication_id: id}) );
    }
  });
}
```

*Edit:* In this version if console.log just articles I get:

```
child {length: 23, models: Array[23], _byId: Object, constructor: function, url: "/articles"…}
```

which also just prints an empty array. I know that data I seek is in the database so if I do the correct thing I should not be getting empty arrays back.

How do I use the _.where function to grab my subset of the collection? Also open to better methods. Hopefully the answer will be obvious to somebody more experienced!

*SOLUTION! **

```
  delete_publication: function(id){
    var articles = new SimpleGoogleReader.Collections.Articles();
    articles.fetch({
      success: function(data){

        _.each(data.models, function(item){
          if (item.toJSON().publication_id == id) {
            console.log(item.toJSON());
          }
          // console.log(item.toJSON().publication_id);
        });

      }
    });
  }
```

Rida BENHAMMANE does it again! The above code prints to the console only the JSON objects of the articles I want.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(articles)` yet? Please paste the output.

Comment: Why do you say that `console.log(articles)` prints an empty array if it prints `child {length: 23, models: Array[23], _byId: Object, constructor: function, url: "/articles"…}`? I'm confused

Comment: it prints an empty array when I try to console.log the result of the .where function. It prints the above output if I just console.log articles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the second method with the `success` callback that will work, just check if the returned models have the `publication_id` set :

```
_each(data.models, function(item) {
    if (item.publication_id) {
        console.log(item);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var filtered = _.where(data, {
  publicationId: id
});
```

http://underscorejs.org/#where

Answer (score 0):

The success callback on fetch returns a jqXHR not the collection you are operating against.
You could rewrite your call like this and use the closure you have on articles.

```
delete_publication: function(id){
  var articles = new MyProject.Collections.Articles();

  articles.fetch().then(function(){
    console.log(articles.where({publication_id: id}));
  });
}
```